# Uniqueness of log function with relaxed conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, functions

### Question

If:

$$f(a) + f(b) = f(ab)$$
$$ f(1) = 0 $$
$$ a<b \implies f(a) < f(b)  \forall  a,b \in N  $$

where $N$ is the set of natural numbers.

Prove or disprove $f$ must be the $\log$ function.

### Background

I was recently wondering about the uniqueness of a function given:

$$f(a) + f(b) = f(ab)$$
$$ f(1) = 0 $$
$$ a<b \implies f(a) < f(b)  \forall  a,b \in R^+  $$

where $R^+$ is the set of positive real numbers.

All of these imply it must be the $\log$ function. I was wondering however what would be the consequence of relaxing the third condition

$$a<b \implies f(a)<f(b)  \forall  a,b \in N $$

where $N$ is the set of natural numbers.

This would allow $f(x)$ to be a combination of the $\log$ and number theoretic functions such as $A(x)$. Where

$$A(x) = \text{number of prime factors of $x$}$$

We note,

$$ A(x) + A(y) = A(xy)$$
$$ A(1) =0 $$

Comment: A (6) = 2. A (15)=2.  A(6*15)=3 $\ne $A (6) + A (15)

Comment: @fleablood its not the number of distinct primes ...

Comment: "number of prime factors of x"  " its not the number of distinct primes" Huh?! 6 has 2 prime factors.  15 has 2 prime factors.  6\* 15 = 90 has 3 $\ne$ 2 + 2.

Comment: Me unsure about what your trying to say  ...  Number of prime factors of $6=3 \times 2 \to 2$ and $15=3 \times 5 \to 2$. Hence, $90= 15 \times 6 = 3^2 \times 2 \times 5 \to 4$  ... Hence number of primes $4= 2+2$ ... However if I said distinct prime factors of $x$ then you would be correct ...

Comment: Oh... I wouldn't have called that "number of prime factors" so much as some other term such as sum of prime powers or some such.  It did not occur to me that that was what you meant A to be.  It should have occured to me that such an A function would satisfy but somehow it didn't occur to me to think of such an A.

Comment: Okay, that function satisfies $A(xy) = A(x) + A(y)$ but it fails $a < b \implies f(a) < f(b); a,b < N$.  8 < 9 but A(8) = 3 > A(9) = 2.

Answer (score 2):

It can be shown by induction on $p$ that $f(a^p) = pf(a)$ for any integers $a,p \geq 1$.

We will prove that $f(n) = \log_b n$ for some $b > 1$. After multiplying $f$ by a positive constant, we may assume $f(10) = 1$.

Let $n$ be fixed. We will prove that $f(n) = \log n = \log_{10} n$. Otherwise, we have either $f(n) < \log n$ or $f(n) > \log n$.

Assume $f(n) < \log n$. Then there exists a rational number $r/s$ such that $f(n) < r/s < \log n$. Then 
$$f(n^s) = sf(n) < r = rf(10) = f(10^r),$$
so $n^s < 10^r$. It follows that $n < (10^r)^{1/s} = 10^{r/s} < 10^{\log n} = n$, a contradiction. Thus the hypothesis $f(n) < \log n$ was absurd.

The condition $f(n) > \log n$ can similarly be proved absurd. Therefore $f(n) = \log n$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this result will follow if you assume that given primes $p_1,p_2$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists integers $n_1,n_2,n_1',n_2'$ such that
\begin{equation}
1-\epsilon<\frac{n'_1\log p_1}{n'_2\log p_2}<1<\frac{n_1\log p_1}{n_2\log p_2}<1+\epsilon
\end{equation}
With this approximation, you can argue that $f(p_1)/f(p_2)$ is arbitrarily close to $\log p_1/\log p_2$ and conclude with the proof.

I don't have a reference for this property of primes but intuitively it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: p1 and p2 don't need to be prime.  Can always find $p^n < q^m$ so $p^n/(p^n)^{\epsilon} < p^n < q^m \implies (p^n)^{1- \epsilon} < q^m \implies (1 - \epsilon)*n \log p <  m \log q \implies 1 - \epsilon < \frac{n \log p}{ m \log q}$. etc.